# Change default shell

Tags: visual-studio

I installed powershell 7, which set itself as the default shell. It messed up some apps, and I removed it. However, it's still registered as the default shell in some places. One of them is VS2022. When I build my project:

```
2>Target PostBuildEvent:
2>  The system cannot find the path specified.
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file C:/prj-external-libs/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary C:/8/_tmp/cpp/build/src/Debug/proj.exe -installedDir C:/prj-external-libs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
2>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 3.
2>Done building target "PostBuildEvent" in project "proj.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>
2>Done building project "proj.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in general it's done via: options> environment> terminal> restore default.

However, in my case, the issue was with cmake vcpkg, which created a post build event using power shell 7. Need to delete (or just ignore) this event, or rebuild a fresh cmake.